# How to accurately simulate a transient Response for a RC circuit with Initial Conditions

Tags: circuit-analysis, pspice, transient

[image]
I am trying to simulate this circuit with the specified initial condition voltages.
If I don't include the parallel R10, I get a Floating Node Error at Vout and have to include it. When I do include it, R10 changes the time constant of the circuit and the voltage at Vout goes to zero depending on the magnitude of R10.

What is the best way to simulate this circuit without running into floating node error and not modifying the time constant of the circuit?

Comment: The Vout node is indeed floating without R10. The rank-nullity theorem also gets in the way here. It's galvanically isolated. And spice simulators are ***not*** charge-conserving, much as that might be desired. (I'm assuming you want to see how charge moves based upon initial conditions.) You cannot fix the floating node problem without adding a galvanic connection. But you can make R10 arbitrarily large -- large enough to see much of anything legitimate that you want to see. Just make sure that the charge "leaking" through R10 is "small enough" for your purposes at hand.

Comment: @periblepsis If I use a fixed 1x10^15 valued resistor as R10, and change the time duration of my transient simulation, I get faster rise time if I simulate for a shorter duration. Do you have any idea why this may be?

Comment: Likely this is because the simulator is using a variable time-step. You can over-ride that.

Comment: How can I do this in pspice? Is this related to the max step size parameter?

Comment: One way is to just set the .TRAN to a short period, like 1 microsecond? Another is to use the maximum timestep field and set that to something small like 1 nanosecond? (Also, instead of a resistor you could consider using a current source with zero amps. LTspice doesn't require either the resistor or the current source, as the author(s) have added some "tricks" to handle this case without the 'floating node' problem.)